# Git Webhooks with AWS services template doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm following the instruction [here](https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-git2s3/doc/git-to-amazon-s3-using-webhooks.pdf) in order to automate deployment of static site from GitHub to S3.

However, when I started the template (with the right region us-east-1, the default template is Ohio us-east-2), I have these errors:

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::KMS::Key   KMSKey  Resource creation cancelled
17:45:43 UTC-0500   
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource CopyZips    Failed to create resource. See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2019/01/29/[$LATEST]...
```

I check CloudWatch Log and get this:

```
[ERROR] 2019-01-29T22:45:41.776Z    ... Exception: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

It looks like the S3 bucket that contains the template or the zip file doesn't exist anymore. Can you help?

I tried the template with default region: us-east-2 and it works.

Thank you.

Comment: did you change the region in your template

Comment: The template does not contain a hard-coded region.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking but maybe it'll help: AWS recently added deployment to S3 support to Codepipeline. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-s3deploy.html for an example. You can replace CodeCommit with Github as the Source phase.

Comment: @Milan Cermak Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GitHub (not GitHub enterprise) then CodePipeline supports webhooks out of the box and you don't need to use the method described in that white-paper.

Instead, you can simply add a GitHub action to your pipeline via the console. If you're using CloudFormation you can find instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-webhooks-create-cfn.html

CodePipeline also recently added S3 deploy action which can simplify that too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-s3deploy.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying the template from your link but it doesn't seem to work for me. The template I found, I've been able to built the stack but cannot configure it to take the build folder from my repo to push to an S3. Do you know a good source I can check?

Comment: Here's an example containing a YML template: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/samples/codepipeline-github-events-yaml.zip

Comment: I followed your suggestion and still unable to do it. I'll have to ask another question. Thank you. I'll mark your answer as correct.